# Is 'quiescing' a valid word? What does it mean?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context, is-it-a-word, present-participles

What does *quiescing* mean in the following context?

> Quiescing a Database

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/start.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Quiescing a Database" [refers to:](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/start.htm#i1006629)

> Occasionally you might want to put a database in a state that allows only DBA transactions, queries, fetches, or PL/SQL statements. Such a state is referred to as a quiesced state, in the sense that no ongoing non-DBA transactions, queries, fetches, or PL/SQL statements are running in the system.

"Quiescing" is basically the action of putting the database into a **quiesced state**

Yes, "quiescing" is a valid word, as can be seen in this [Wiktionary article:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quiesce)

> quiesce (third-person singular simple present quiesces, **present participle quiescing**, simple past and past participle quiesced)

Nota Bene: Emphasis added

Comment: Hi Ham, I can't found the words `quiesce` and `quiescing` in any of my dictionaries. Where can I find the definition of these words? Thanks.

Comment: @Yousui, at Wiktionary

Answer (score 3):

http://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Aquiesce - I personally used this word in the late '80s and '90s

When Quiescing a database, you allow all currently running transactions to finish, but any new transaction sees a stopped database.

From the IBM command reference:

> Without the ability to quiesce the
>   database, you would need to shut down
>   the database and reopen it in
>   restricted mode. This is a serious
>   restriction, especially for systems
>   requiring 24 x 7 availability.
>   Quiescing a database is much a smaller
>   restriction, because it eliminates the
>   disruption to users and the downtime
>   associated with shutting down and
>   restarting the database.

[Definition for quiesce:](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn)

> quieten: become quiet or quieter;
>   "The audience fell silent when the speaker entered".

[Quiesce - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiesce)

> Quiesce is used to describe pausing or altering the state of running processes on a computer, particularly those that might modify information stored on ...

[Quiesce - definition of Quiesce by the Free Online Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Quiesce)

> v. i., 1. To be silent, as a letter;
>   to have no sound. [ imp. & p. p. Quiesced ; p. pr. & vb. n. Quiescing .]

[Quiescing a Database](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start004.htm)

> The quiesced state lets administrators perform actions that cannot safely ... Without the ability to quiesce the database, you would need to shut down the ...

[QUIESCE Command](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/start004.htm)

> QUIESCE DATABASE results in all objects in the database being in the quiesced mode. Only the allowed user/group and sysadm, sysmaint, dbadm, ...

[Quiesce | Define Quiesce at Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quiesce)

> quiesce definition. networking. To render quiescent, i.e. temporarily inactive or disabled. For example to quiesce a device (such as a digital modem). ...

Answer (score 3):

You have some technically accurate definitions, and for what it's worth here's mine.

> Quiesce means finish what you're doing, don't start anything new, to become quiet.

I first heard the word used in game theory describing the process of seeking a relatively quiet state of gameplay when iterating or recursing through the tree of possible moves. In chess for example it could be seeking a position where no captures or threats are available. To quiesce means (as I understand it) to literally seek a quiet place.

http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Quiescence+Search

Comment: @Guiness, the question is in context of technical stuff i.e. computing

Comment: @Guiness, I think that the definition you provided wouldn't apply in this case, but that's only what I think... I may possibly be wrong

Comment: @Ham it was with databases and recursive algorithms in mind that I gave this answer.